# infinite scroll nextjs ISR or SSR

Tags: next.js, interrupt, next.js13

How do i use infinite scroll fetching data  in ISR component or SSR component ?

I'm trying to use Infinite Scroll fetching data using ISR or SSR component in nextjs 13.4

so is there is any way to use infinite scroll in ISR OR SSR?

Answer (score 1):

Infinite scroll can be realized with 'react-intersection-observer'. For both SEO and user-friendly infinite scolling I use pagination together with the observer. The observer return `inView` flag that triggers a page parameter update. The `setObserver` sets a state to conditional render the observer.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setObserver(true);
  if (inView) {
    const param = (page + limit).toString();
    setQueryParameter(param);
  }
}, [inView]); // eslint-disable-line
```

The page is a Server component in the App folder that fetches the data with a limit and page (skipped number of records).

```
export default async function Home({ searchParams }: AppPageProps) {
  const param = searchParams[RouterParamTypes.Page];
  const page = param ? parseInt(param) : 0;
  const docs = await getDocs(page, PAGE_LIMIT);
```

The data is passed to a Client component that saves the data in React state. When on the client the state gets updated in a useEffect each time new data is loaded.

```
export default function Infinite({ docs, limit, page }: DocInfiniteProps) {
  const [state, setState] = useState<DocType[]>(docs);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.length + limit <= page) {
      router.replace('/');
    } else {
      setState(state.slice(0, page).concat(docs));
    }
  }, [docs, page]); // eslint-disable-line
```

The web-crawler renders the page once and receives a paginated list. Optional add a next and prev reference for the web crawler.